# Trying to limit scroll area inside a UIScrollView when displaying the keyboard after a UITextField becomes active in iOS

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, autolayout, uitextfield

I am working on a project where I have a `UIView` that contains multiple UI elements, including a `UITextField`.  Once the `UITextField` becomes active (i.e. `becomesFirstResponder`), the keyboard that pops up covers up the `UITextField`.  The `UIView` which contains all of the UI elements resides inside a `UIScrollView`.

Now, aside from moving up the contentView into the visible area of the `UIScrollView`, another thing I need to do is ensure that the user is unable to scroll the contentView below (and behind) the keyboard, nor scroll the contentView above (and behind the navigation bar).

The relevant code I have thus far is:

```
-(void)keyboardDidShow:(NSNotification *)notification {
    CGFloat height = [[notification.userInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size.height;
    self.scrollViewBottomContstraint.constant = height;
    [self.view layoutIfNeeded];

}
```

Can anyone show me how to ensure that my contentView can minimally scroll within ONLY the visible area between the navigation bar and the keyboard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the keyboard notification appears, I would:

1. Change your constraint constants on the `UIScrollView` so that it is size to just the visible portion of the screen. You've started down this path with the height setting for the bottom constraints.
2. Change the `contentSize` property on the `UIScrollView` to match. This way, any scrolling that the user performs, is confined to what is visibly accessible to them.

When the keyboard goes away, you can revert back to previous settings, before you made these adjustments.

Note that in some cases, using a UITableView with static table cells and static content inside them, can be easier. The iOS runtime seems to handle some of the scroll to be visible stuff for you.

Answer (score 1):

This might be helpful for you.

```
//KEYBOARD SHOWN
    - (void)keyboardShown:(NSNotification*)notification
    {
        NSDictionary* dic = [notification userInfo];
        CGSize keyboardSize = [[dic objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;
        UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, keyboardSize.height, 0.0);
        scrollView.contentInset = contentInsets;
        scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets;

        CGPoint scrollPoint = CGPointMake(0.0, textField.frame.origin.y-keyboardSize.height);
        [scrollView setContentOffset:scrollPoint animated:YES];

    }

      //when keyboard hides
    - (void)keyboardHidden:(NSNotification*)notification
    {
        // Set the Scroll view content inset to UIEdgeInsetsZero
    }
```